"Bad offset for central directory" with openpyxl on AWS Lambda only
I'm using FastAPI and openpyxl to upload and parse an Excel file. It works well on my local machine, but when I deploy my API to AWS Lambda, I get the following error: "Bad offset for central directory"
Other posts suggest the file is corrupt, but it works fine when uploading locally. I'm testing with the same exact file.
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook

def upload_report(file: UploadFile = File(...))

        contents = file.file.read()
        buffer = io.BytesIO(contents)
        wb = load_workbook(buffer, data_only=True)  # Error thrown here.

        ...

Using Python 3.12, fastapi 0.111.0, and openpyxl 3.1.5

Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74800326/26993270 ?

"getvalue" doesn't exist on the File object I'm using.

The linked SO Post suggests you are only getting the name of your zip file not the contents. Have your checked?

@moken Not sure how to check when it's deployed in a Lambda. The same xlsx file works locally. I can try to add more logging to see what's going on.

The issue has to with how AWS API Gateway handles binary data as described in this post Enabling binary support using the API Gateway
That is, it must be specifically configured to be accepted or the data gets converted to base 64 in the pipeline.
Configure API Gateway for multipart/form-data content.

Navigate to API Gateway.
Click API settings.
Click Manage media types.
Enter multipart/form-data, and click Save changes.
Click Resources.
Expand your Resources and select /{proxy}+.
Select ANY.
Click Method request, and click Edit.
Expand HTTP request headers.
Add the following two headers: Accept and Content-Type.
Click Save.
Click Deploy API.

